# Username and Password Validation in TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, passwords, password-protection

I'm trying to write a simple function to validate a username and password that a user would input.

*The username has the following validation rule:*

- The email must from a university (.edu) or .gov or .org

*- The password has the following validation rules:*

- At least 10 characters (and up to 30 characters)
- 5 or more unique characters
- At least 3 of the following: uppercase, lowercase, numeric, or special characters.  The allowed special characters are ~ ! @ # $ % ^ * - _ = + [ { ] } / ; : , . ?
- password cannot contain email or any part of your name
- cannot contain number sequences of 4 or more numbers
- cannot contain character repeated 4 or more times

So far, I have:

```
var email;
var password;
var firstname;
var lastname;

validate (email, password, firstname, lastname)
{
    //email validation 
    var substring1 = ".edu";
    var substring2 = ".gov";
    var substring3 = ".org";
    if (console.log(email.includes(substring1)) || 
    console.log(email.includes(substring2)) || console.log(email.includes(substring3)))
    {

        if (password.length < 10 || password.length > 30)
        {
            return "password length must be at least 10 characters and no more than 30.";
        }
        else if (password.contains(firstname))
        {
            return "password may not contain user's first name";
        }
        else if(password.contains(lastname))
        {
            return "password may not contain user's last name";
        }
        else if(password.contains(email))
        {
            return "password may not contain user's email";
        }
        else if(password.contains((.)\1{4,}))
        {
            
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return "username is invalid."
    }

}
```

I don't know how to approach these rules:

- cannot contain number sequences of 4 or more numbers
- cannot contain character repeated 4 or more times
- 5 or more unique characters
- - At least 3 of the following: uppercase, lowercase, numeric, or special characters.  The allowed special characters are ~ ! @ # $ % ^ * - _ = + [ { ] } / ; : , . ?

I would appreciate any insights or tips as to how to get started?

Comment: by "cannot contain character repeated 4 or more times" it means you can not have: 1a2a3a4a or sequence of character repeated 4 times is not allowed?

Comment: @AmirMB sequence of characters repeated 4 times!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year later but better later than never. What you want to achieve can be done with Regex patterns, used appropriately in the right context.

> At least 10 characters (and up to 30 characters):

```
/^\S{10,30}$/m
```

Test: `mypassword`

> 5 or more unique characters

```
/^(?=.{7,})([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*(?!\1)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*(?!\1|\2)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*(?!\1|\2|\3)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)([a-z\d])[a-z\d]*$/m
```

Test: `mypassword` vs `mypassssss`

> At least 3 of the following: uppercase, lowercase, numeric, or special
> characters. The allowed special characters are ~ ! @ # $ % ^ * - _ = +
> [ { ] } / ; : , . ?

**Uppercase**:

```
/^.*[A-Z]{3}$/m
```

Test: `mypasswordABC`

**Lowercase**:

```
/^.*[a-z]{3}$/m
```

Test: `mypassword`

**Numeric**:

```
/^.*[\d]{3}$/m
```

Test: `mypassword123`

**Special Characters**:

```
/^.*[~!@#$%^*\-_=+[{\]}\/;:,.?]{3}$/m
```

Test: `mypassword!@#`

> cannot contain number sequences of 4 or more numbers

**Numeric match**:

```
/^([0-9])\1{3}$/m
```

Test: `1111` vs `1234`

> cannot contain character repeated 4 or more times

**Character match**:

```
/^([a-zA-Z])\1{3}$/m
```

Test: `aaaa` vs `abcd`

I do not have time to combine them all into one and test, but it is possible. For now you can simply add a few lines with .test for each of them.